# Creating a bed model

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL - Server 2012

I’ve been asked a create a Bed Model for our local hospitals to assess bed utilisation summarised by specialty
The problem is I need to report every midnight a bed is occupied and the only 2 pieces of data, per patient, 
I have to generate this analysis is the patients’ Date of Admission and Date of Discharge from hospital

An example of how the report is shaping up in my mind is

```
Local trust #1  No. of Beds Occupied at midnight                    
    Month - May                     
Specialty   01  02  03  04  05  ….  30  31
General Med 58  57  64  61  42  …   52  53
General Surg.   75  74  75  73  53  …   75  71
T&O     84  85  86  84  74  …   83  85
```

At patient level
    Patient #1  Admission date  - 20/5/19   Discharge date - 24/5/19

```
            Date            
Specialty   19/05   20/05   21/05   22/05   23/05   24/05
General Med 0   1   1   1   1   0
```

It’s almost as if I need to create a row for each day, which would involve a loop of some description, adding 1 day to the admission date until it equals the discharge date.

Taking my example above, the output “table” would contain…
    Patient #1 20/5/2019
    Patient #1 21/5/2019
    Patient #1 21/5/2019
    Patient #1 22/5/2019
    Patient #1 23/5/2019

I can see how to go about this in my mind but I can't seem to get it off the ground
Is my suggestion feasible and the best approach? I’ve read loops are frowned up on

In anticipation, thanks for any input you can offer

An example of how the report is shaping up in my mind is

```
Local trust #1  No. of Beds Occupied at midnight                    
        Month - May                     
Specialty   01  02  03  04  05  ….  30  31
General Med 58  57  64  61  42  …   52  53
General Surg.   75  74  75  73  53  …   75  71
T&O     84  85  86  84  74  …   83  85
```

Comment: In addition to the poor formatting which discourages people from reading (much less understanding) your post, your question is off-topic for being far too broad and for being subjective. "Best" for you may not be "best" for anyone else. A technical question like this should start with a script containing DDL and sample data in a simplified form along with the expected results from that sample data.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. Please move this to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: We have similar reports to the one you're tasked with.  Before you create another new table to store this data, is there an existing one that you can access that already contains the patient-bed assignments?  You must have a EHR source system where patients/treatment/admit/discharges are all managed?

Comment: I don't work at a hospital and therefore I don't have access to a patient administration system
My org receives extracts of patient based data from this and other hospitals so we can monitor our expenditure in each hospital and we don't have access to their bed allocation system. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> It’s almost as if I need to create a row for each day,

Close.  You need a table with a row for each day.  Then you can join that to the patient visits to get a row per patient per day.

something like:

```
select d.date, v.department, v.patient_id
from dates d
join visits v
  on v.admit_date <= d.date and v.discharge_date > d.date
```